# Not loading images from one framework when having two frameworks containing same images as resources in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, xcframework

This is something I stumbled across and it is really a mystery to me for some time now. I have two frameworks; let's call them `FrameworkA` and `FrameworkB`. I have built them, and created two formats for them `.framework` and `.xcframework`, so I have 4 frameworks in a nutshell. All of them have the same images as resources within a framework, I do not have separate `bundle` for resources. When using `.framework` aka `fat binary` in my App, when opening my `ViewController` from `FrameworkB`, its images are not loaded. I have checked and got path for bundles and images for `FrameworkA` and `FrameworkB`, and they are:

- `FrameworkA` - `path/FrameworkA/image.png`
- `FrameworkB` - `path/FrameworkB/image.png`

I tried to use them inside my app, and that's working, I can load the same image from A and B frameworks and add them to two sample `ImageView`s to check if I can load them from framework bundles. When I remove `FrameworkA`, images are loaded correctly when using `ViewController` from `FrameworkB`.
When I remove both frameworks as `.framework` and add frameworks as `.xcframework` format to my App, paths for images are exactly the same:

- `FrameworkA` - `path/FrameworkA/image.png`
- `FrameworkB` - `path/FrameworkB/image.png`

but now, my images inside `ViewController`, when calling it from `FrameworkB`, are there; they are being populated as expected.
If I remove `FrameworkA.xcframework` and add it as `FrameworkA.framework`, then again, `ViewController`s images are NOT being populated as expected, it's exactly like having two `.frameworks` format.
I am using Xcode 12.4 for my builds. Do you know where to look more, and what to try?

Comment: Can you post the code where you load/create the image?

Comment: Also, when you do these changes add/remove .framework/.xcframework, do you clean the project, delete derived data etc?

Comment: Try using directly `imageNamed` initializer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624154-imagenamed?language=objc, that should work ok. Swift version https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624154-init

Comment: I am loading images with imageNamed, and I’ve tried without caching contents of file image init. I am also telling from what bundle to load them. I am cleaning my project end removing derived data every time I change my framework combination.